# How to get WebDev.WebServer40.exe installed on windows 10?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have some old legacy code that requires:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\webdev.webserver40.exe
```

but how do I install that? From the above it seems I need to install VS 2010 so I tried to download VS 2010 Express:

*en_visual_studio_2010_vb_express_web_installer_x86_516528*

and install that, but that did not install anything in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\webdev.webserver40.exe
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That server is ASP.NET Development Server and your "legacy" code should not depend on it at all. Revise that to use other solutions please.

Besides, if you do insist installing it, you need to install Visual Studio Express for Web, not VB.